# how to style ngtable with expandable detail?

Tags: css, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to style a ng-table layout, which contains a table in each row. The way this expanding functionality is implemented in angular, looks like this:

```
<tr ng-if="org.expanded" ng-repeat-end>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

The issue is more related to CSS.

The problem is that, when clicking on the plus icon next to the ServiceType column the 4 expanded columns aren't aligned with the parent tablecolumn headers i.e. Service Type, Location , Contact details and Last Updated.

**How can I set it, that the values look nicely aligned(left)?**

**Also, I can't align the Last Updated column to the left.**

Here is a plunkr sample of the problem:
http://embed.plnkr.co/UlMg7J/preview
http://plnkr.co/edit/UlMg7J?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

For the last column not aligned issue I have replaced the table for phone,website..etc with divs and it started to align to the position you desired. What it was doing was it was creating extra headers (th) tags which is not desired.

Your Code:

```
<td data-title="'Contact Details'">
    <table>
        <tr>
             <td>Phone:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Fax:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Email:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Website:</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</td>
```

Changed Code:

```
<td data-title="'Contact Details'">
    <div>Phone:</div>
    <div>Fax:</div>
    <div>Email:</div>
    <div>Website:</div>
</td>
```